# How to use GeoJson as a Formatconstructor on DragAndDrop in Openlayers

Tags: typescript, openlayers

I followed this example from openlayers:
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/drag-and-drop.html

But my project is built on typescript and the Geojson format gives the following error:

> Type 'typeof GeoJSON' is missing the following properties from type 'FeatureFormat': dataProjection, defaultFeatureProjection, adaptOptions, getReadOptions, and 8 more.

This is the code I use and the error appears on the Geojson in the formatconstructors.

```
import { defaults, DragAndDrop } from 'ol/interaction';
import {GeoJSON} from 'ol/format';


this.dragAndDropInteraction = new DragAndDrop({
    formatConstructors: [GeoJSON]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to overrule the typescript checking as following

```
this.dragAndDropInteraction = new DragAndDrop({
    formatConstructors: [GeoJSON as any]
})
```

Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9448